# Deactivate anti-aliasing when deleting a selection in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, anti-aliasing

I have a simple task to complete with Photoshop that i'm not able to do.

I have an image which i want to select an area and delete it **without anti-aliasing**, i want to cut to the exact selected pixels.
I don't understand why it always apply anti-aliasing and delete outside of the selection border, and the anti-alias checkbox is grayed and uncheked.

Can somebody help me ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you deleting with the eraser tool or by using the marquee tool to select then hitting the delete button? If it is the eraser, you are probably using a soft brush, if the marquee, it could be your refine edge settings.

Either way, you should almost never use either of these options in Photoshop. Instead use a layer mask. A layer mask applied to your layer can drive the visibility in a non-destructive manner. Basically you paint in black and white on the mask, where black is transparent, grey is semi transparent, white is fully visible.

The huge advantage of the non-destructive workflow is that you never actually delete any pixels - you just hide them. Later if you want them back, you can just paint them back in your layer mask.

Comment: Thanks for your help John, but even with the layer mask I have the exact same problem. I clicked on "Add mask", I selected a zone with the marquee tool, painted it in black with the paint bucked, and I get the same result shown in the image above.

Comment: But the Refine edge settings was the solution ! Constrast was at 0%, setting it to 100% solved the problem, thanks !